# Python Object Oriented structure

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I am new to python and I come from C# background. I was reading a book on Python and came across a statement that a class is an object in Python. I am not quite sure if it is true because I tried to look it up online and couldn't find an answer. Could someone please explain?

Here is a paraphrase of what the writer says:

> program units such as functions, modules, and classes are objects in Python too

And could someone also elaborate why this is the case as in C# objects are derive from class.
Like Car is a class and Honda, Mercedes is an object of that class. But as i am reading it seems in Python class is an object. So car is an object, Honda and Mercedes are also an object so what is the benefit of class?

Comment: Yes, it's true. Everything in Python is an object. I don't think Guido particularly cares if Java and C++ don't do things the same way.

Comment: Voted to reopen as this question is clear enough and answerable.  Clearing up this cross-language confusion could be helpful for others.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski How is this answerable?  Is there a single, choosable answer to "Is there any benefit" when discussing implementations?  There are, it seems, many correct answers, indicating to me that it's too broad.

Comment: @Wooble I know Guido don't care but my purpose is solely academic. As what is the main benefit of this approach over conventional approach. I am not leaving it because there is no class derived system. I like Python too.

Answer (score 3):

When one creates a class in Python:

```
class Frabbah:
    """
    A soothing class, designed to ease tensions on StackOverflow.
    """
```

one then has a thing, or an object, that one can work with:

```
--> print(Frabbah)
<class '__main__.Frabbah'>
```

and one can add attributes to it:

```
--> Frabbah.answer = 'Interesting...'
```

and then look them up:

```
--> print(Frabbah.answer)
Interesting...
```

Pretty much everything in Python is a thing, or a first-class citizen, meaning you can pass these things around, inspect them, modify them, etc., etc.  So an integer as an object, a class is an object, a function is an object...

Comment: Thanks. But what is confusing to me, as you can understand for people coming from different language, when i have object(super set) and everything is derived from it than it means i don't need class(subset) i can use object and than that object can has attributed and functions. Because here you have object than derive a class from that object than derive object from that class. ???

Comment: We also don't need loops, as `goto`s would serve the same purpose.  Higher level languages exist to make certain things easier, not because this or that construct is absolutely necessary.  As for `object` and its instances -- they are special in that they do not have an in-built `dict`, so you cannot add things to them, you need to subclass.

Comment: So objects can't directly have attributes and functions they need to be part of a class to have full benefits of class system. Right?

Comment: `object` has a default set of methods, which if not overridden in a subclass are actually used.  But *new* methods and attributes cannot be added, nor (I think) existing methods/attributes changed.